# Multiple conditions in exp in informatica?

Tags: expression, informatica

In Exp,for one port(datatype:string) I have to check 8 different conditions.How Can i do it?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: By using an IIF function and/or AND and OR functions? Please provide details of the logic you are trying to implement (by updating your question)

Comment: To summarize @nickw's point, use nested `iif`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the requirements, either:

- use one `IIF` statement connecting all your conditions with AND
- use `DECODE` function if only one of the conditions will be met (it lets you avoid the nested IIFs)